# Create Django object outside a view using modeltranslation

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation, django-1.6

I'm writing some tests and I need to create some objects but I get this error when I try to create some object outside a Django View

```
cat = Category.objects.create(catalog=c, name="Category one")
```

Returns

```
TypeError: 'name_es' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This fails with modeltranslation 0.6.1 but works with 0.3.2

`name` is a field translated with modeltranslation.

From the docs:

> The unittests use the django.utils.translation.trans_real functions to
>   activate and deactive a specific language outside a view function.

I've tried this:

```
trans_real.activate('es')
cat = Category.objects.create(catalog=c, name="Category one")
```

And I get the same error :(

Anyone knows a better way for testing modeltranslation based models in Django?

### EDITED

More things tried so far:

```
cat = Category.objects.create(**{'catalog':c, 'name': 'Category one'})
TypeError: 'name_es' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: there is also deactivate function, did you try that? `deactivate()`

Comment: I get the same error with `deactivate()`

Comment: Have you tried passing the attributes as a kwargs dictionary to create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the solution by looking at the docs [here](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#auto-population)

If you want to create a category name in all the languages:

```
x = Category.objects.populate(True).create(name='Category one')
```

And if you want to create it in a specific language:

```
x = Category.objects.create(name_en='Category one')
```

This works for django-modeltranslation version 0.6+